# Custom WC Email templates

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i follow [this tutorial](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/create-custom-email-templates-woocommerce/) to create a custom email plain text with specific parameters to send SMS when a new order is confirmed.

i follow all instructions but i change action like this :

```
    // template path
    define( 'CUSTOM_TEMPLATE_PATH', untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '/templates/' );
    // hook for when order status is changed
    add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', array( &$this, 'custom_trigger_email_action' ), 10, 2 );
    // include the email class files
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', array( &$this, 'custom_init_emails' ) );
```

I translate a little to adapt with my language (French).

**Woocommerce > Settings > Emails**
I can see my custom template email but i have an issue. He doesn’t want to find Email Templates in the directory.

This is what i have now :

```
Name of plugin/
——————–/custom-email-manager.php
——————–/emails
—————————–/class-custom-email.php
```

Everything works until here because i can manage Custom Email in woocommerce’s settings.

at step 3 Dev say

> follow Woocommerce structure

then

```
Name of plugin/
——————–/custom-email-manager.php
——————–/emails/
—————————–/class-custom-email.php
——————-/templates/
———————————/emails/
——————————————-/custom-item-email-html.php
——————————————-/plain/
—————————————————/custom-item-email.php
```

Can help me to understand my mistake ?

Best regards.

Comment: Looks like you may have edited the code with a document processor, as you have non ascii single quotes in that code

Comment: Hi, i edit code with Notepad++ who give me good result anyway i change to standard quote nothing change. Still don't find any emails/templates_htmland email/plain/template_plain_text. Thx for answer.